# Where should I sell old bike parts?

Tags: parts

I seem to have amassed a huge collection of bike parts. Some parts are old and need a specialist market so I don't think that ebay is the best marketplace for them. How can I sell on / give away old bike parts so I know that  I'm getting the best price and/or reaching the right audience.

Comment: I would try Craig's List.  If you want to give some away, look for a local organization that rebuilds old bikes for charity.

Comment: Not sure why you think ebay isn't right. I don't know of any better market for old obscure parts. Do some searches for what you have to sell and compare.

Comment: Indeed, Ebay is a good place even for vintage stuff. You can also check VeloBase.com.

Comment: Sell?  I clean mine, service them, and carefully store them for the next usage.  Sometimes I give them away to someone else with a need, knowing that I'm earning a favour for my next requirement-scrounge.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the urban-ness of your area, there may be local "bike swap" events once or twice a year. If you really have a lot to get rid of, this could be one way to get it in front of the right people.